# Can I get the Jenkins master key from Hashicorp Vault?

Tags: jenkins, hashicorp-vault

as you probably know, Jenkins uses a key stored in plain text in a file in the master server to encrypt the credentials. From security perspective that is not a good approach. Is there any way of telling Jenkins to take the key from Hashicorp Vault?

Comment: there isn't any plugin like that at the moment in Vault